# Combinations between elements in two tuples in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have two tuples:

```
t1 = ('A', 'B')
t2 = ('C', 'D', 'E')
```

I wonder how to create combinations between tuples, so the result should be:

```
AC, AD, AE, BC, BD, BE
```

**EDIT**

Using

```
list(itertools.combinations('abcd',2))
```

I could generate list of combinations for a given string:

```
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

If I insert tuple instead of string the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

Any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: You will greatly increase your chances of getting an answer for your question if you include your input, _what you have tried_, your expected output vs. your actual output and the full stack trace of any errors you receive. You can also read [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: itertools has something for it

Comment: What does nCr have to do with that?

Comment: ^nCr would list all the possible combinations of values from 2 sets, so that would be a perfect fit.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see, that question wasn't actually about the math nCr function that would just calculate the amount of calculations. Makes sense, and yes, that is a possible duplicate.

Comment: The apparent goal here is to determine the pairings, not count them. Furthermore, these are **not "combinations"**. Thus, the prior duplicate of the nCr question was in fact completely inappropriate.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does exactly what you are looking for:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> t1 = ('A', 'B')
>>> t2 = ('C', 'D', 'E')
>>> list(itertools.product(t1, t2))
[('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E')]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(t1, t2)]
['AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'BC', 'BD', 'BE']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for value_one in t1:
    for value_two in t2:
        result = (str(value_one), str(value_two))
        print result
```

This uses no external libraries. Literally just two for loops and string concatenation. Format the output however you'd like.

This seems like you either did not put any effort into finding this answer, or I am misinterpreting the question.

Edit: I see that you are coming from an R background, so you may not understand Python syntax. Please refer to guides for Python basics; I believe they will help greatly. To save the values from the loop, as @Naman mentioned, you will want to make an empty list and `[list_name].append([value])` the desired values, then print the values in the list using other constructs.

Answer (score 2):

All possible combinations:

```
import itertools

t1 = ('A', 'B')
t2 = ('C', 'D', 'E')

print(tuple(itertools.combinations(t1 + t2, 2)))
```

Output: `(('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'E'))`

Comment: I need only combinations between tuples. Any idea how to delete others?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple method:

```
for i in t1:
    for j in t2:
        print(i+j,end="")
```

This three line of input  gives the above combinations.

Comment: Best not to rely on a bit of print syntax to join them together on one line, when the OP might not want to print it. `string.join` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can print what you want by iterating over both the tuples(or make an empty list and store your output in that list)

```
l = []
for c1 in t1:
    for c2 in t2:
        print c1 + c2 + ',',
        l.append(c1 + c2)
```

Finally list `l` will contain the output elements. You can process its elements or make a tuple of it by

```
t = tuple(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = []
for x in t1:
    for y in t2:
        t.append(x+y)

t = tuple(t)
```

So iterate over both tuples, append every combination to a list and then convert the list back to a tuple.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the `range(0, len(t[#])` is unnecessary in Python; you can simply use the list/tuple/dict/etc. name to loop over all of the constructs values.

Comment: You are actually right. Thanks, I will fix that

Comment: What was the downvote for?